# Why Does NSDateFormatter return a nil on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsdateformatter

When runDate value is   @"Fri, 01 Nov 2013 08:47:33 GMT-0500", I get nil on iOS 7 iPhone simulator, but it's ok on iOS 6 iPhone simulator

```
        NSString *runDate = [reportDictionary objectForKey:@"runDate"];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";

        NSDate *actualRunDate = [formatter dateFromString:runDate];
```

I end up with an actualRunDate of nil on iOS 7 simulator but not on iOS 6.1

How can I get it to work on iOS 7?

Comment: The timezone format should be `ZZZZ` (4 Zs, not 3).

Comment: @rmaddy Probably the solution. But note that the time-zone can be 3 or four letters depending on how it supplied: "Time Zone – with the specific non-location format. Where that is unavailable, falls back to localized GMT format. Use one to three letters for the short format or four for the full format. In the short format, metazone names are not used unless the commonlyUsed flag is on in the locale."

Comment: Using this format, I still got a nil. @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"

Comment: runDate __NSCFString * @"Fri, 01 Nov 2013 08:47:33 GMT-0500" is an example string

Comment: Can you double-check the suggestion by @rmaddy? According to the docs, it should've worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think I see what is happening.

According to the docs you can specify three 'ZZZ' characters for dates in the format:

```
Fri, 01 Nov 2013 08:47:33 -0500
```

And you can specify four 'ZZZZ' characters for dates in the format:

```
Fri, 01 Nov 2013 08:47:33 GMT-05:00
```

***Note the colon character in between the GMT hours and minutes!***

Therefore, I think the solution (if you can't change the date format you're getting), is to set the formatter as follows:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZZ";
```

. . this will skip over the 'GMT' part, treating it as a date in the 'ZZZ' format.

As pointed out in the comment by @rmaddy, this solution assumes that all dates have the letters 'GMT' in the timezone. If they're expressed in relation to some other timezone, then you'll have to fix the format of the date you're being supplied, or perhaps parse the string manually first (extract those characters with a regular expression or something), if you simply can't do that.

The ideal solution is to fix the date format being supplied to the client, however according to the principles of *contract-first development* we should be as tolerant as we can (assuming this date that you need to parse is being consumed from a remote service with many down-stream subscribers, all of which might have to change if the format was corrected).

Comment: The last solution only works if all of your date strings reference `GMT`.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove GMT from the string you're trying to parse and have it look like this

```
@"Fri, 01 Nov 2013 08:47:33 -0500"
```

the date returned will be correct. Everything else seems to be fine.